# ほしがっている versus ほしそうだ

Tags: grammar, suffixes, auxiliaries, modality

I don't really understand the differences between the following sentences.

- 彼は新しい車をほしがっている。
- 彼は新しい車をほしそうだ。

In both sentences, the speakers made conjectures based on the sign that the third person (彼) is showing.

## Question

1. What is the difference between the 2 sentences above?
2. Can I rewrite the second one as 彼は新しい車をほしがっていそうだ。Is it redundant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

彼は新しい車をほしがっている can mean

1. He wants a new car （＝ …車が欲しいと思っている）
2. He is showing his desire for a new car

彼は新しい車**が**ほしそうだ means "He looks desirous of a new car".

彼は新しい車をほしがっていそうだ is usually taken as something like "I assume he is now begging a new car".